# Hyperlink wrapping a video tag - wrong target set for click handler

Tags: javascript, html

I have run into this odd situation and would like someone to explain this to me...

Given this code:

```
  <a id="foo" href="http://www.google.com/">
    <video width="400" controls>
      <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
      Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
    </video>
  </a>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    'use strict';

    var wrapper = document.getElementById('foo');

    wrapper.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      console.log('Clicked', e);
    });
  }());
  </script>
```

Why is the "target" always the video tag and never the "a" tag?

Comment: Where is "target", do you mean e.target ?

Comment: Specifically I'm wondering why the "a" tag never seems to trigger the event listener I have attached. I'm not stopping propagation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean e.target, it refers to the clicked element, which is the video tag. On click event, the `<video>` tag does not have an event handler, so nothing is executed. Then the event is raised (bubbled) to the parent element `<a>` tag which has the event handler you specified. The `<a>` tag can be accessed using `this` inside the event handler

To understand what is happening clearly, read about Event Bubbling topic.